# How do I resolve this issue when trying to host my Jekyll site on Github Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm a total complete beginner at using Jekyll. I want to deploy my site on Github Pages. However, when I tried at first, I got a bunch of errors when I checked my workflow, and I'm not sure how to fix them. I'm using a custom built Jekyll theme called jekyll-simple-blue

```
Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioactionsjekyllbuildpagesv108_8f6cd9 --label 124adb --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_DESTINATION" -e "INPUT_TOKEN" -e "INPUT_FUTURE" -e "INPUT_BUILD_REVISION" -e "INPUT_VERBOSE" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/website/website":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.8
Warning: the running version of Bundler (2.1.4) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.4.20). We suggest you to upgrade to the version that created the lockfile by running `gem install bundler:2.4.20`.
Resolving dependencies...
The dependency tzinfo (>= 1, < 3) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for x86_64-darwin-22, ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32 java`.
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for x86_64-darwin-22, ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32 java`.
The dependency wdm (~> 0.1.1) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for x86_64-darwin-22, ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32, x86-mswin32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32 x86-mswin32`.
The dependency http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for x86_64-darwin-22, ruby but the dependency is only for java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform java`.
The following gems are missing
 * public_suffix (5.0.3)
 * addressable (2.8.5)
 * ffi (1.16.3)
 * google-protobuf (3.24.4)
 * sass-embedded (1.69.3)
 * jekyll-sass-converter (3.0.0)
 * rexml (3.2.6)
 * kramdown (2.4.0)
 * mercenary (0.4.0)
 * rouge (4.1.3)
 * unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
 * terminal-table (3.0.2)
 * webrick (1.8.1)
 * jekyll (4.3.2)
 * jekyll-feed (0.17.0)
 * jekyll-simple-blue (0.1.0)
Install missing gems with `bundle install`
Warning:  github-pages can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:84:in `rescue in gemspec': The jekyll-simple-blue theme could not be found. (Jekyll::Errors::MissingDependencyException)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:81:in `gemspec'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:19:in `root'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `configure_theme'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:55:in `config='
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-228/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-228/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll-simple-blue' (>= 0) among 146 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/github/home/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/local/bundle', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/specification.rb:986:in `find_by_name'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:82:in `gemspec'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:19:in `root'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/theme.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:439:in `configure_theme'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:55:in `config='
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:23:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-228/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-228/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `<main>'
  Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml
             Theme: jekyll-simple-blue
github-pages 228 | Error:  The jekyll-simple-blue theme could not be found.
```

Additionally, when I uncommented the following `gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins` and deleted `gem "jekyll", "~> 4.3.2"` (as mentioned in the default Gemfile file that was generated) I got the error `Could not find gem 'github-pages'.`

All help is greatly appreciated!